# Using composition to apply a decoration

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I am trying to use the composite design pattern to apply decorators.   Most of the resources that I have come across state that these two patterns often work together in that way, but none show examples of how this works.   Probably a stretch, but could I have an example to extrapolate implementation from in this case?

An outline of my classes are stated below.

ThorSoldier inherits from AvengerSoldier, AvengerSoldier inherits from Unit.    Each "Avenger" follows a similar structure.

```
class Unit // Component (Not abstract, contains all the implementations that units have)
{
    public:
        virtual void levelUp(){}
    // Other implementations
};

class NickFurySoldier // Manager (Composite)
{
    public:
        virtual void levelUp();// Should apply the decorators to primatives
        void add(Unit* avenger);
    private:
        std::vector<Unit*> avengers;
};

class ThorSoldier: public AvengerSoldier
{
    // Example of a primative that has to be decorated
};

class ThorDecorator: public ThorSoldier
{
    public:
        ThorDecorator(ThorSoldier* soldier);
    // Other Implementations
};

class LightningThor: public ThorDecorator // Example of the decoration that should be implemented
{
    public:
        LightningThor(ThorSoldier* soldier);
    // Other implementations
};
```

Comment: what is your question??

Comment: I've asked my question more explicitly now